# Odd behaviour when capturing an Eigen::Vector in std::function

Tags: c++, eigen, std-function

I have the following code

```
Eigen::Vector2d xT = Eigen::Vector2d(1.7, 3.4); // chosen at random

std::function<Eigen::Vector2d(Eigen::Vector2d)> test1 = [xT](Eigen::Vector2d x)
{ 
    Eigen::Vector2d y = x - xT;
    return y; 
};

std::function<Eigen::Vector2d(Eigen::Vector2d)> test2 = [xT](Eigen::Vector2d x)
{ 
    return x - xT; 
};

std::cout << "\n" << test1(xT) << "\n"; // outputs (0, 0) i.e. x - xT
std::cout << "\n" << test2(xT) << "\n"; // outputs (-1.7, -3.4) i.e. -xT
```

I would think that both test1 and test2 should output the same results. Yet test2 is outputting erroneous results (it is evaluating at (0,0) rather than at xT). What is happening here?

I tried similar things with doubles rather than Eigen::Vector2d but everything worked fine.

Comment: Instead of doubles, you may test a similar thing by passing `x` as (const) reference. In that case, everything also works fine. Reference works but value does not, it sounds even weirder for me.

Comment: If you change `Eigen::Vector2d y = x - xT;` to `auto y = x - xT;`, the first version won't work either. The issue seems to be close to old https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/505 .

Comment: Interesting MSVC 17 returns <0,0> while GCC 12.2 returns <0,0> and <-1.7,-3.4>.  I am using Eigen 3.3.9.

Comment: Your `test2`  lambda expression returns an expression template which depends a temporary that gets destructed before the ET is evaluated to a `Vector2d` -- therefore you have undefined behavior. I suggest to pass `x` by const reference.